# Query of two Tables with JOIN and LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables

The First table with Persons

```
person_id | person_name
```

Second table is Books

```
book_id | person_id| book_name
```

The Books should be limited to 3 per person, and I want the result like this.

```
Person 1
Book 1
Book 2
Book 3

Person 2
Book 4
Book 5
Book 6

Person 3
Book 7
Book 8
Book 9
```

I'm using the following query

```
$load = "SELECT persons.person_id, persons.person_name, books.book_id, books.book_name, books.person_id, FROM persons LEFT JOIN books ON persons.person_id = books.persons_id";
```

But this gives a record for every book associated to each person, and adding a LIMIT will cause some people to not appear in the results. How can I LIMIT the results per person while still getting all people in the table?

Comment: Can you post the result of your query?

Comment: Start with specifying what database you're using in your question. BTW to the question "*My query is wrong. What should I do?*" I would answer: fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on the RDBMS you use.

If you are using Postgres (or Oracle), you can use a window function to rank your results:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        persons.person_id, 
        persons.person_name, 
        books.book_id, 
        books.book_name, 
        books.person_id AS books_person_id,
        rank() OVER (PARTITION BY persons.person_id ORDER BY books.book_id) AS rank
    FROM persons
    INNER JOIN books ON persons.person_id = books.person_id
) AS foo
WHERE rank <= 3;
```

MySQL is missing window functions, so it is a bit more tricky. We will then use user defined variables:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        persons.person_id, 
        persons.person_name, 
        books.book_id, 
        books.book_name, 
        books.person_id AS books_person_id,
        CASE persons.person_id
            WHEN @prevVal THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
            ELSE @curRank := 1 AND @prevVal := persons.person_id
        END AS rank
    FROM persons
    INNER JOIN books ON persons.person_id = books.person_id,
    (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevVal := null) AS foo
    ORDER BY persons.person_id ASC
) AS bar WHERE rank <= 3;
```

Comment: Thank You! I using MySQL. Unfortunately i get a follow Error if i use your code. 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE persons.person_id, WHEN @pre' at line 26

Comment: I fixed a typo in a field name, along with a duplicate column name I had. If that still doesn't work, what is your current MySQL version? You can also remove the `books.person_id` field from SELECT at it'll match the one from `persons` table.

Comment: Thank You very much!!! It works!!!
Where did you learned SQL? Have you some sources of Online-Books for me where i can improve my sql knowledge? I have never seen things like @ or := in SQL-Syntax. :-( The Online-Documentation is a little bit complicated for me. I using MySQL Server-Version 5.6.26. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I mostly used Postgres in the past, and I had a similar query to make. It is easier to find how to rank results if you know it exists and how it is called. Glad it helped you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear, but this may be all you need.  Start with a simple query first.

```
SELECT book_name, book_id
FROM  books, persons
WHERE books.person_id = persons.person_id
ORDER by books.person_id
```